# How to check if an AWS SageMaker endpoint already exists?

Tags: aws

I am using the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemaker/AmazonSageMaker.html), and I want to delete a SageMaker endpoint and a SageMaker endpoint config. What is the best way to do this?

For example, I am currently first using the `describeEndpoint` method to see if the endpoint already exists. I do this by calling `describeEndpoint` and if I get an exception that includes the phrase `Could not find endpoint`, then I know the endpoint does not exist.

That way, I can only call the `deleteEndpoint` method if the endpoint already exists, as it will otherwise throw an exception. This feels like a very inelegant solution. Can we do better?

Comment: I think it probably does.  But after doing some more research, It looks like the [listEndpoints](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/SageMakerClient.html#listEndpoints-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.ListEndpointsRequest-) method is probably even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`search`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/SageMakerClient.html#search-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.SearchRequest-) method to search for the resource. And [`SearchResponse`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/model/SearchResponse.html) object contains `hasResults()` boolean method.

And in [`resource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_Search.html#API_Search_RequestSyntax) attribute, endpoint is one option that you could provide.

The name of the Amazon SageMaker resource to search for.

> Type: String
>
> Valid Values: TrainingJob | Experiment | ExperimentTrial |
> ExperimentTrialComponent | Endpoint | ModelPackage | ModelPackageGroup
> | Pipeline | PipelineExecution | FeatureGroup
>
> Required: Yes

**EDIT**

As discussed in comment, an alternative way is to use [`listEndpoints`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/SageMakerClient.html#listEndpoints-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.ListEndpointsRequest-) in which [`nameContains`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/SageMakerClient.html#listEndpoints-software.amazon.awssdk.services.sagemaker.model.ListEndpointsRequest-) field can be constructed with the endpoint name in the request, and call [`hasEndpoints()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/model/ListEndpointsResponse.html#hasEndpoints--) on the response.